# KSysGuard and htop show different cpu usage for my app

Tags: cpu-load, htop

I'm developing an app and I want to know how much CPU it takes. The problem is that KSysGuard shows 8%, while htop shows 30%. How do I know which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=225&t=127047):

> rightclick the cpu column header and untick "divide by cpu amount"